# Authenticating Requests From A Single Server

Tags: api, security, oauth

I'm working on a project which contains data belonging to multiple clients, and I'm trying to find a secure way to notify their servers of certain sensitive changes to their data.

The issue is that the most secure method I found for this is OAuth, but since my server will be pushing the updates to them, that would mean that each client would have to implement an OAuth provider solely to authenticate my server, and it feels like a bit of an overkill.

My question is: Keeping in mind that not all clients will use HTTPS, would it be enough to simply use a shared secret, a timestamp, and some form of encryption for their servers to safely receive and validate my updates or will that leave them vulnerable to attacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would be secure.  For simple messages I think [JTW](https://jwt.io/introduction/) would be a very good choice.  You could use it for just authentication or the actual notification itself. A few reasons you might want to use it:

- It's signed, so you know the message hasn't been tampered with.
- You can encrypt with public/private key pairs.
- You can add any data you like.
- It's very simple to implement and doesn't require back-and forth exchange between servers like OAuth often does.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented the steps I indicated in the question manually but I prefer standardized libraries so I'll probably switch to JWT.